# Clear hash and parameters from Redirect in aspnet mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect

Consider the following code within a controller:

```
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!this.IsAuthorized) 
        {
            filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "" });
            //filterContext.Result = Redirect(Url.Content("~/Home/Index")); // Gives same result as the previous row
            return;
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

If I enter the follwing url when not authorized:

```
somecontroller/someaction#/?tab=Foo
```

I get redirected to:

```
/Home/Index#/?tab=Foo
```

How come the hash isn't stripped from the url?
How can I get rid of it serverside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. The named anchor (`#/?tab=Foo`) is not part of the request, the browser does not send the named anchor to the server. Take a look at [named anchors are not sent to the web server](http://web.archive.org/web/20090508005814/http://www.mikeduncan.com/named-anchors-are-not-sent/)